# Trying to run code in IOKE shell results in error?

Tags: java, windows, jvm, ioke

When I try to execute code in the IOKE shell it crashes.

```
 >ioke
 iik> "Hello World" println
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ioke.lang.IokeIO$2.activate(IokeIO.java:129)
            at ioke.lang.TypeCheckingNativeMethod.activate(TypeCheckingNativeMethod.java:50)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Message.sendTo(Message.java:999)
            at ioke.lang.Message.evaluateCompleteWithoutExplicitReceiver(Message.java:1145)
            at ioke.lang.Message.getEvaluatedArgument(Message.java:979)
            at ioke.lang.Message.getEvaluatedArgument(Message.java:983)
            at ioke.lang.FlowControlBehavior$9.activate(FlowControlBehavior.java:379)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Locals$1.activate(Locals.java:63)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Message.sendTo(Message.java:999)
            at ioke.lang.Message.evaluateCompleteWith(Message.java:1093)
            at ioke.lang.LexicalBlock.activate(LexicalBlock.java:198)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.LexicalBlock$2.activate(LexicalBlock.java:86)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Message.sendTo(Message.java:1011)
            at ioke.lang.FileSystem$7.activate(FileSystem.java:308)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Message.sendTo(Message.java:999)
            at ioke.lang.Message.evaluateCompleteWithoutExplicitReceiver(Message.java:1145)
            at ioke.lang.ConditionsBehavior$4.activate(ConditionsBehavior.java:342)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Locals$1.activate(Locals.java:63)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Message.sendTo(Message.java:999)
            at ioke.lang.Message.evaluateCompleteWithoutExplicitReceiver(Message.java:1145)
            at ioke.lang.Message.getEvaluatedArgument(Message.java:979)
            at ioke.lang.Message.getEvaluatedArgument(Message.java:983)
            at ioke.lang.FlowControlBehavior$7.activate(FlowControlBehavior.java:298)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Locals$1.activate(Locals.java:63)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Message.sendTo(Message.java:999)
            at ioke.lang.Message.evaluateCompleteWithoutExplicitReceiver(Message.java:1145)
            at ioke.lang.ConditionsBehavior$4.activate(ConditionsBehavior.java:342)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Locals$1.activate(Locals.java:63)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Message.sendTo(Message.java:999)
            at ioke.lang.Message.evaluateCompleteWith(Message.java:1093)
            at ioke.lang.DefaultMethod.activate(DefaultMethod.java:283)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.activate(IokeObject.java:1053)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:1038)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.getOrActivate(IokeObject.java:514)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:659)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:592)
            at ioke.lang.IokeObject.perform(IokeObject.java:522)
            at ioke.lang.Message.sendTo(Message.java:999)
            at ioke.lang.Message.evaluateComplete(Message.java:1066)
            at ioke.lang.Runtime.evaluateString(Runtime.java:525)
            at ioke.lang.Main.main(M

ain.java:149)
```

What is causing this to error? I'm using Windows 10, my IOKE_HOME and JAVA_HOME env variables are set (Otherwise the REPL wouldn't be invoked in the first place). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this has to do with Ioke attempting to use some Java API to retrieve the user's home directory. I found that the problem reproduced on Linux when running Ioke as any user who did not have a home directory, despite the `HOME` environment variable being set. I was able to work around the problem by setting the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable:

```
$ JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.home=$PWD" ioke
```

Note that similar problems occur with other Java-based programming languages such Kotlin, and the same workaround can sometimes be applied. Clearly, somebody made a very poor design decision deep down in the Java APIs.

**Note that Ioke has been completely abandoned since 2011, and is unlikely to receive any updates or support in the future.**